# Undefined control sequence. --\nameref

Tags: nameref

I am using IEEETran document class, from https://www.computer.org/web/tpds/author

My LaTeX source looks like:

```
(See \S\ref{AnyLabel}--\nameref{AnyLabel}.)
. . .
\section{AnySec}\label{AnyLabel}
```

I get this error:

> Undefined control sequence. (See \S\ref{AnyLabel}--\nameref

If I omit `\nameref{AnyLabel}`, I get the correct section number with no error.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you load the `nameref` package?

Comment: Bingo!  That was it.  Thanks for the amazingly fast response.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the `\nameref` macro, the [nameref](https://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package has to be loaded.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section{Fancy Section Header}\label{sec:fancy}
\dots

See \S\ref{sec:fancy}--\nameref{sec:fancy}.
\end{document}
```